# get system wallpaper in my application in ios

Tags: ios

I am new in ios app building, in recently working on image app developing and I want to get system wallpaper in my app so user can aslo select one of them easily. but I really don't know how to get system images.

Comment: You can't, they are not accessible via the public SDK.

Answer (score 0):

With the public SDK you can't. Maybe using undocumented methods, but this will cause reject from Apple.

Comment: ok, so I have to add other wallpaper in my app look like ios provided ?